# JavaScript for Loop timeout

Tags: javascript, for-loop, timeout

I seen this loop , and I don't understand how after the second loop ( when I = 2 ) the timeout is still 4 second and not 7 seconds.

- First loop , i = 0 , x = 0 , and the output is 0 after 1 sec - i understand why
- Second loop , i = 1 , x = 1 , and the output is 1 after 4 sec - i understand why 3000 X 1 + 1000 = 4000 ( 4 sec )
- Third loop , i = 2 , x = 2 , the output is 2 after 4 sec - **why 4 sec and not 7** ? 3000 X 2 + 1000 is 7000 ( 7 sec ) but why i get the output after 4 sec and not 7 ?

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  (function(x) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(x);
    }, 1000 + (3000 * x));
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing console logs every 3 seconds, starting 1 second after clicking the button...

Comment: @Cerbrus Same here. The code seems to run just as expected, all outputs with 3-second intervals and all with an offset of 1 s.

Comment: But after the Third loop it should be 7 sec no ?

Third loop , i = 2 , x = 2 , the output is 2 after 4 sec - why 4 sec and not 7 ? 3000 X 2 + 1000 is 7000 ( 7 sec ) but why i get the output after 4 sec and not 7 ?

Comment: @AngusYoungus 7 seconds from the start. Not from the previous iteration. One is 1 second from the start, one is 4 seconds from the start and one is 7 seconds from the start. There are 4 seconds between each of them.

Comment: @Ivar: There are 3 seconds between each of them. But other than that, correct, all timeouts start at the same moment. They don't start after the previous one finished.

Comment: @AngusYoungus I think you might be looking at the wrong numbers. I'm getting the exact output as expected. First output was a `13:45:23`, second was `13:45:26`, third was `13:45:29` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout for i, x = 2 is 7 seconds. That is why it happens 3 seconds after i, x = 1 fires. This function as written does not register the next timer when the previous timer fires, it registers all 10 within a few milliseconds of being called, They go off at 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, and 31 seconds.

This one, however, will have a longer delay between each one. The key is registering the next timer as the current one is firing instead of all 10 at once.

```
function timeRecurse (i=0) {
    var next = () => timeRecurse(i +1)
    console.log(i);
    return (i < 10) ? setTimeout(next, 1000 + (3000 * i)): null;
}

timeRecurse();
```

Comment: How can I change the loop and the function to wait every time 3 seconds more then the previews , for example first output after 1 sec then after 4 sec then after 7 sec , 10 sec ….

Answer (score 0):

The current execution plan is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, all the executions were relative to the starting point (almost).

If you wanted the executions to happen one after the other (0 after 1 second, 1 after 5 seconds, 2 after 12 seconds), then do this:

```
function compoundedInterval(x, limit) {
    if (x > limit) {
        return;
    }
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(new Date(), x);

        compoundedInterval(x + 1);
    }, 1000 + (3000 * x));
}

compoundedInterval(0, 10);
```

I've updated the `console.log` to add the time so we can see the actual gaps between executions.

I now have the ff. results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is 7 seconds delay for third iteration, but from start of the script, not from second iteration. It is because of asynchronous nature of javascript.
All timeouts will start at the same time and each console output will happen 3 seconds after previous one.

Check javascript event loop for more information.
For example, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) pretty nicely explains that topic in my opinion.